# Adding information to an already existing xml folder from a windows form

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to store the information that is writen into a form with the following code but what keeps happening is that it just override the one that there is already no add to it. I have the following code with xml serilaztion.

```
 XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer((iClass.GetType()));
 writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
 xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, iClass);

 CreditCard cc = new CreditCard(cardNumber, expiryDate, creditCardType);
 User u = new User(name, surname, gender, posistion, wage, amount, bankType, cc, username, password);
 XmlSave x = new XmlSave(u, "customers.xml");
```

I have to try to keep the same format because it is for a school project.

Comment: Do you have the code for XmlSave? I don't recognise that as part of the .NET framework.

Comment: public XmlSave(object iClass, string fileName)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = null;
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer((iClass.GetType()));
                writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, iClass);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Close();
                writer = null;
            }
            
        }